# How to change `Figure 1` to `1 Figure`?

Tags: floats, captions

How is it possible to fine-tune the appearance of the figure caption to invert the name and the number in figure captions?

I know I can easily redefine `\figurename` and `thefigure` but how do I change their order?

Note that options such as:

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{figure} Fig}
```

would not be an option, since referecing will not work.
Many thanks!

Comment: What language are you writing in? `babel` and the suiting langauge definition file might take care of the issue. If not, what documentclass are you using? Can you prepare a minimal working example? Package `caption` can certainly do what you need.

Comment: I am using LaTeX. Both answers are very good. I have chosen the one using `caption` since this is probably what most people will need.

Comment: Welcome! It would be better if you include a minimal example of code, so as to show more precisely your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) allows you to reformat the label configuration using `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat`, where `#1` represents the caption name/type, and `#2` the number/reference:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

% #1 = name, #2 = number
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{numname}{#2~#1}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat = numname}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

See Figure~\ref{fig:figure}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure caption.}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any packages, you can redefine `\fnum@figure` which lays out the arrangement between `\figurename` and `\thefigure`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% Default
% \def\fnum@figure{\figurename\nobreakspace\thefigure}
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{\thefigure\nobreakspace\figurename}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

See Figure~\ref{fig:figure}.

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A figure caption.}
  \label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```